# Please migrate this question to an appropriate site

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, migration

I'm talking about the question: [Is Rama Setu a historical proof of Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44332/4732)

It is quite obvious that the question isn't suitable for our site and that's why it is closed as well.
It can't be answered using sources which are allowed on this site. And, hence you can see an attempted answer uses sources (like newspaper articles) which aren't accepted here.

But I believe it may have better responses if moved to an appropriate site where experts in the field of history, archaeology are present.

So, I request the Mods to do the needful and migrate the question to an appropriate site like History.SE. If you know about another site where it's more suitable (than History) then suggest that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The said question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44332/647) is moved to [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/63123). We have also informed mod of History.SE about the migration.

Comment: You discuss the possibility of migration first or you migrate first and then just inform the mods of History.SE about it?

Comment: @Rickross latter

Comment: Very brief reply to understand anything clearly :P. But, I assume you meant to say that you migrate first and inform the other site later.

Comment: @Rickross haha yeah that's what I meant.